# Serverless Framework - Choose between static iam resource ARN and reference from Resources section

Tags: if-statement, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless framework to deploy a lambda, and optionally a dynamo db table the lambda accesses.

In development stages sls creates the table as a full fledged resource (and therefore I have a reference to the table)

Alternately, in production stages sls does not create the table, but a custom variable knows the precreated table's ARN

Having problems crafting the Resource clause of the lambda's iam policy document, probably because I'm not understanding the allowable mix between Cloudformation IF statements and sls dynamic variables.  Here's as far as I've gotten (abbreviated):

```
provider:
  ... unrelated stuff
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - dynamodb:DescribeTable
            - ..more DynDB permissions
          Resource:
            - !If [ ${self:custom.slsMadeTheTable},  Fn::GetAtt:[MyDynDBTable, Arn], ${self:custom.staticArnOfPrecreatedTable} ]
```

Where:

${self:custom.slsMadeTheTable} refers to a boolean valued string from custom variables that defines whether sls made the table (so get its reference and use it in resource) or not (so use a known static Arn)

${self:custom.staticArnOfPrecreatedTable} is a custom variable whose value is a literal ARN string of a precreated DDB table

In this particular configuration I get a syntax error suggesting I've incorrectly combined the Cloudformation `if` with sls expressions.

```
Cannot parse "serverless.yml": missed comma between flow collection entries in "../serverless.yml" (64:22)
  

   64 |             - !If [ ${self:custom.slsMadeTheTable},  Fn::Ge ...
  ---------------------------^
```

Tried many other variants, none successful.

Looking for help crafting a policy that will *either* handle a created DDB table or a precreated ARN of a table depending on a determining variable (tied to stage of course)

**--- Another failing approach ---**

The Resource is happy to accept an ARN string in a custom variable, e.g.

```
Resource: ${self:custom.productionTableArn}
```

So you'd think a simple defaulted expression would do the trick, along the lines of

```
Resource:
  ${self:custom.devTableArn, 
self:custom.productionTableArn}
```

Where the self:custom.devTableArn contained the contents of the created DDB table.

But the reference to the sls ddb table arn: `"Fn::GetAtt": [ TunesTable, Arn ]` which works perfectly fine as a direct entry for the resource, fails when set as a value for self:custom.devTableArn:

```
devTableArn: "Fn::GetAtt": [ TunesTable, Arn ]
```

with the error:

```
Cannot parse "serverless.yml": bad indentation of a mapping entry in "/home/rpc/tune-library-tunes/serverless.yml" (24:28)
   24 |   devTableArn: "Fn::GetAtt": [ TunesTable, Arn ]
```

Comment: Where have you seen such a construct with `IF` in sls?

Comment: @Marcin - at https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam#at-glance it says: "Alongside provider.iam.role.statements managed policies can also be added to this service-wide Role, define managed policies in provider.iam.role.managedPolicies. These will also be merged into the generated IAM Role **so you can use Join, Ref or any other CloudFormation method or feature here too**."

Answer (score 0):

The key to the problem was realizing that SLS is, as often stated, **mainly** a wrapper to CloudFormation (CFN).  More than I'd thought.   CFN scripting is executed during CFN deployment, not SLS interpretation.

So any association between a DynDB SLS resource and a custom expression is purely syntactic.  Inserting `"Fn::GetAtt": [ TunesTable, Arn ]` in our IAM resource isn't in a context that is aware of a TuneTable in SLS, it doesn't calculate and substitute, it *literally* sticks the string into the CFN template, to be executed later for good or ill.

Knowing that narrowed the problem to 'what expressions in CFN will work and can SLS generate them' which led to a plugin solution from https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-ifelse.  I hope the functionality is included in a future base SLS release (but with a simpler syntax).